# Не работает исключение

Tags: python

Код выводит возраст:

```
def retrieve_age(person):
      try: 
        return int(person["age"])
      except ValueError: 
        print("Вы некорректно ввевили возраст")
      except int(person["age"])<=0:
        print("Вы ввeли отрицательный возраст") 
print(retrieve_age({"name" : "Max", "age": -5}))
```

Вопрос:

```
except int(person["age"])<=0:
            print("Вы ввeли отрицательный возраст")
```

Это не работает. Как создать пользовательское исключение против отрицательного ввода?

Comment: А что тут должно обрабатываться, тут `age = 5`, то есть число, нормально тут всё

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что после except может стоять условие? Это во-первых. А во-вторых, если аргумент может быть преобразовать в число, неважно, положительное или отрицательное, то на return все и заканчивается.

Comment: Просто это исключение почему-то не работает, даже если только его оставить

Comment: @CrazyElf даже если отрицательное число поставить, оно не обрабатывается почему-то

Comment: @lalalend Потому что вы это должны в if проверять сами и бросать исключение вручную. И ловить его потом отдельно. Если уж хотите с исключениями

Answer (score 3):

Просто условный оператор нельзя?:

```
if int(person["age"])<=0:
            print("Вы ввeли отрицательный возраст")
```

Comment: Не, надо кастомный ексепшн. Как я понял, его с классом надо создавать? это типо пользовательский?

Comment: @lalalend , а зачем вам исключение, если if все преспокойно решает????

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
class SubZeroError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        
class MyInt(int):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = int(num)
        if self.num<=0:
            raise SubZeroError
        super().__init__()


def retrieve_age(person):
    age = person["age"]
    try:
        age = MyInt(age)
        return age
    except ValueError:
        return "Вы некорректно ввевили возраст"
    except SubZeroError:
        return "Вы ввeли отрицательный возраст"
        
print(retrieve_age({"name" : "Max", "age": -5}))
```

Comment: @lalalend, если вам помог ответ, вы можете отметить его как полезный (галочка слева от ответа)